# Jade/Express Blocks not Showing Up

Tags: express, pug

I did a lot of searching on this topic and have found nothing that will help me out, it seems. I am trying to render header and footer using the `block` and `extends` feature of jade, rather than includes.

Here is what I have and I can't seem to understand why it will not render.

`layout.jade`

```
html
  head
   title= title

  body
   block header
   block content

   footer
     block footer
```

`index.jade`

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

`header.jade`

```
extends layout 

block header
  h1 this is a header
```

`footer.jade`

```
extends layout

block footer
  h2 this is a footer
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misinterpreting what 'extending a template' means. Each template that extends `layout.jade` should be compiled into a page of its own. That is, `layout` defines a blueprint for how each page that extends it should look. The inheritance pattern here does not go both ways: When seeing that the `layout` template has a `footer` block, pug does not search all other templates for possible block implementations. Instead, you tell it to compile child templates, like the `index` template.

What I would suggest in your case is the following: Either have the footer and header content either directly included in `layout.jade`, or `include` it without the `block` statement.

Do keep the `index` template as is - IMHO, that's the correct usage pattern for template inheritance.

Comment: I am coming from laravel where Blade the templating engine uses that feature. And that is where the confusion came from. Thank you for explaining it, I was trying to get away from using the include feature.